# magento2 website and its admin panel showing blank screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, magento2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub4XL.png)[image]

**root permission is working fine with sudo su.
cache:clear is working fine.
reindex:index  is working fine.
Developer mode is working fine.
production mode is  working fine.**

Comment: rename pub/errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml then you can know what is the error in website

Comment: when you try accessing the url, what does your browser network tab show?

Comment: Thank Do you mean what is showing in browser its blank url is not moving its just stays on domain name.

Comment: Hi Jinesh,I did it still I can't see any error

Comment: Hello go to app/bootstrap.php uncomment line 12 for showing all errors (ini_set('display_errors', 1))

Comment: i can see error

Comment: now another error coming which i have attached image line                             
   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Catalog\Model\NoSuchEntityException' not found in /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php:141

Comment: We can't read some files that are required to run the Magento application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly. Any idea about this error